# How can I learn DOCUMENT_ROOT in startup.pl under mod_perl2?

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2, document-root

I want to learn DOCUMENT_ROOT in startup.pl, but the best I can do is to learn server_root:

```
use Apache2::ServerUtil ();
$server_root = Apache2::ServerUtil::server_root();
```

which is quite useless. I can set an environment variable with

```
SetPerlEnv DOCUMENT_ROOT /path/to/www
```

but I don't like extra configuration if possible.

Is there a way to get DOCUMENT_ROOT by other means?

Comment: CGI, mod_perl, something else?

Comment: App::Info::HTTPD::Apache is a hack, it reads Apache config file. It is not safe. Is there an introspection solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Apache2::Directive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache2::Directive). For example, on my development system:

```
use Apache2::Directive ();
my $tree = Apache2::Directive::conftree();
my $vhost = $tree->lookup(VirtualHost => 'unur.localdomain:8080');

File::Slurp::write_file "C:/bzzzt.txt", [ $vhost->{DocumentRoot}, "\n" ];
```

created a file `C:/bzzzt.txt` with the contents `"E:/srv/unur/deploy/htdocs"` after I discovered that I had to specify my virtual hosts using

```
<VirtualHost unur.localdomain:8080>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost qtau.localdomain:8080>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

rather than `<VirtualHost *:8080>`. Otherwise, each `<VirtualHost *:8080>` section was overwriting the previous one.

This is annoying. I would have thought each `VirtualHost` entry would have been keyed by the `ServerName` used.

As for if there is an easier way, I am afraid there isn't if you want to do this in `startup.pl`. However, I am not sure if it is necessary to do it in `startup.pl`. You can find out the document root while processing a request as well using [Apache2::RequestUtil::document_root](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Apache2::RequestUtil).

If you are running [Registry scripts](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html#Registry_Scripts), and want to change to `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, then you should be able to add:

```
chdir $ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT} 
    or die "Cannot chdir to '$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}': $!";
```

to the script instead of having to mess around with `startup.pl` and handlers etc.

Comment: Isn't there an easier solution?

Comment: I couldn't vote up since I didn't have reputation of 15 :-) What I want to do is to chdir to DOCUMENT_ROOT, since I need to run old CGI code with ModPerl::Registry. Is PerlInitHandler alright for this purpose?

Comment: @codeholic Sorry, forgot about the 15 points thing. Thank you for accepting my answer.